# Create Docker Image For JRE FROM scratch

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a image using JRE without any OS. I tried this Dockerfile which does not work.

```
    FROM openjdk:11.0.1-jdk-oraclelinux7 as JDK
    RUN jlink --no-header-files --no-man-pages --add-modules java.base,java.desktop,java.logging,java.sql --output /jre

    FROM scratch
    #FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
    COPY --from=JDK /jre /jre
    ARG JAR_FILE
    COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar
    CMD ["/jre/bin/java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

I am getting following error:

```
    standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

If I replace scratch with oraclelinux, it works fine. Any clue why I cannot use scratch. The reason to use scratch is to reduce the size of the image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use Oracle? I'm asking because of their license...

Comment: I want to create image from scratch and not oraclelinux. Oraclelinux usage was just part of debugging.

Comment: I've just read again first sentence... docker is just a group of processes + chroot + network virtualization. System is needed. For instance to install JDK, with dedicated package manager.

Comment: Please see docker documentation on building image FROM scratch. https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/scratch/ . I am trying to do something similar, it is just not working.

Comment: is the jre produced by jlink a static binary? if not this binary will depend on OS shared libs

Comment: Let me check on the jre..Thanks for the tip..

Comment: You are right...JRE has dynamic linking...to OS libraries..which might be causing the problem..looking more into it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hotspot sources do not currently support statically linking. See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2013-September/010810.html for more info.

Comment: You are citing a source from 2013, that is over 5 years old. Do you know that it is relevant for the OP's problem? If so, can you clarify?

Comment: this answer is correct, although old link. The issue here was that JRE supports only dynamic links which means it needs glibc (and probably others) which are not available in the scratch  image.